# Netbeans IDE Code Snippet Keybinding

Tags: netbeans

I'm not sure if this is possible and if this is the right place to ask, but I'd like to give it a try. I'm currently trying Netbeans IDE, coming from Dreamweaver.

In Dreamweaver I can create Code Snippets and bind a key to them. So for example marking a text and pressing CTRL+B then, surrounds the text with the [strong] tag. Or I created a snippet, when I press SHIFT+CTRL+B it adds a [br /] tag at the position of the cursor.

I could not find a way to do this in Netbeans so far. Does anyone know if this is possilbe, and if, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Plugin available for that,

Go to Tools->plugins and try out TagMyCode

https://tagmycode.com/

I've been using it for quite some time, there is a library of public snippets and the doc is really helpful.

Comment: Thanks, will try out. Does this support Keybindings for snippets of my choice?

Comment: Sadly no, you can do Atl+Shift+CTRL+Space which is "search Snippets" then select the one your created, but you can't keybind directly a Snippet. TagMyCode use a Web Api to create Snippets (Though you can create them directly in NetBeans).

Comment: Yes, thanks, I played around with it a bit. Too sad. Definitly a gap in the Netbeans-Plugins. :)